# Understanding Deferred Execution: Is a Linq Query Re-executed Everytime its collection of anonymous objects is referred to?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently trying to write some code that will run a query on two separate databases, and will return the results to an anonymous object.  Once I have the two collections of anonymous objects, I need to perform a comparison on the two collections.  The comparison is that I need to retrieve all of the records that are in webOrders, but not in foamOrders. Currently, I'm making the comparison by use of Linq.  My major problem is that both of the original queries return about 30,000 records, and as my code is now, it takes waay too long to complete.  I'm new to using Linq, so I'm trying to understand if using Linq to compare the two collections of anonymous objects will actually cause the database queries to run over and over again - due to deferred execution.  This may be an obvious answer, but I don't yet have a very firm understanding of how Linq and anonymous objects work with deferred execution.  I'm hoping someone may be able to enlighten me.  Below is the code that I have...

```
private DataTable GetData()
{
    using (var foam = Databases.Foam(false))
    {
        using (MySqlConnection web = new MySqlConnection(Databases.ConnectionStrings.Web(true)
        {
            var foamOrders = foam.DataTableEnumerable(@"
                    SELECT order_id
                    FROM   Orders
                    WHERE  order_id NOT LIKE 'R35%'
                    AND originpartner_code = 'VN000011'
                    AND orderDate > Getdate() - 7 ")
                .Select(o => new
                {
                    order = o[0].ToString().Trim()
                }).ToList();

            var webOrders = web.DataTableEnumerable(@"
                    SELECT ORDER_NUMBER FROM TRANSACTIONS AS T WHERE
                    (Str_to_date(T.ORDER_DATE, '%Y%m%d %k:%i:%s') >= DATE_SUB(Now(),  INTERVAL 7 DAY))
                    AND (STR_TO_DATE(T.ORDER_DATE, '%Y%m%d %k:%i:%s') <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),  INTERVAL 1 HOUR))")
                .Select(o => new
                {
                    order = o[0].ToString().Trim()
                }).ToList();
            return (from w in webOrders
                    where !(from f in foamOrders
                            select f.order).Contains(w.order)
                    select w
                ).ToDataTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put more time into formatting your code - it's all over the place at the moment.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what's going on, but ToList() executes a query now, so whenever that object is used after, it's already in memory. Try to put a stopwatch at different places to see what's taking really long... if it's the last part with the return, you might want to make a dictionary with a key for each entry, and use that to see what's included or not.

Comment: There is no *deffered* execution. You put whole lists into memory and then execute last `ToDataTable` querry. Fetching **all** records into memory is probably a bottleneck. Try to remove both `ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks SpaceSteak, it is the return statement that is causing the problem.  Would you mind elaborating on your suggestion that I make a dictionary?  Are you saying that I should use .ToDictionary() instead of .ToList() on the two database queries?  If so, how do you recommend I make the comparison afterwards?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linq ceases to be deferred when you do

```
ToDataTable();
```

At that point it is snapshotted as done and dusted forever.

Same is true with foamOrders and webOrders when you convert it

```
ToList();
```

You could do it as one query. I dont have mySQL to check it out on.

Comment: Is this fully accurate, though?  From what SpaceSteak was saying, it sounds like the query results are snapshotted at the point of .ToList(), instead of .ToDataTable().  What do you think?

Comment: I will make it more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding deferred execution:

Method `.ToList()` iterates over the `IEnumerable` retrieves all values and fill a new `List<T>` object with that values. So it's definitely not deferred execution at this point.

It's most likely the same with `.ToDataTable();`

P.S.
But i'd recommend to :

1. Use custom types rather than anonymous types.
2. Do not use LINQ to compare objects because it's not really effective (linq is doing extra job)
3. You can create a custom `MyComparer` class (that might implement IComparer interface) and  method like `Compare<T1, T2>` that  compares two entities. Then you can create another method to compare two sets of entities for example `T1[] CompareRange<T1,T2>(T1[] entities1, T2[] entities2)` that reuse your Compare method in a loop and returns result of the operation

P.S.
Some of other resource-intensive operations that may potentially lead to significant performance losses (in case if you need to perform thousands of operations) :

1. Usage of enumerator object (`foreach` loop or some of `LINQ` methods)

Possible solution : Try to use `for` loop if it is possible.

2. Extensive use of anonymous methods (compiler requires significant time to compile the lambda expression / operator );

Possible solution : Store lambdas in delegates (like `Func<T1, T2>`)

Comment: Thanks Fabjan, I wish I could mark you both as an answer.

Comment: No worries, i's glad to help

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone in the future, my new code is pasted below.  It runs *much* faster now. Thanks to everyone's help, I've learned that even though the deferred execution of my database queries was cut off and the results became static once I used .ToList(), using Linq to compare the resulting collections was very inefficient. I went with a for loop instead.

```
private DataTable GetData()
    {
        //Needed to have both connections open in order to preserve the scope of var foamOrders and var webOrders, which are both needed in order to perform the comparison.
        using (var foam = Databases.Foam(isDebug))
        {
            using (MySqlConnection web = new MySqlConnection(Databases.ConnectionStrings.Web(isDebug)))
            {
                var foamOrders = foam.DataTableEnumerable(@"
            SELECT foreignID
            FROM   Orders
            WHERE  order_id NOT LIKE 'R35%'
            AND originpartner_code = 'VN000011'
            AND orderDate > Getdate() - 7 ")
                                     .Select(o => new
                                     {
                                         order = o[0].ToString()
                                                     .Trim()
                                     }).ToList();


                var webOrders = web.DataTableEnumerable(@"
            SELECT ORDER_NUMBER FROM transactions AS T WHERE
                                                (Str_to_date(T.ORDER_DATE, '%Y%m%d %k:%i:%s') >= DATE_SUB(Now(),  INTERVAL 7 DAY))
                                                AND (STR_TO_DATE(T.ORDER_DATE, '%Y%m%d %k:%i:%s') <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),  INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
                                                 ", 300)
                            .Select(o => new
                            {
                                order = o[0].ToString()
                                            .Trim()

                            }).ToList();


                List<OrderNumber> on = new List<OrderNumber>();

                foreach (var w in webOrders)
                {
                    if (!foamOrders.Contains(w))
                    {
                        OrderNumber o = new OrderNumber();
                        o.orderNumber = w.order;
                        on.Add(o);
                    }
                }

                return on.ToDataTable();

            }
        }


    }


    public class OrderNumber
    {
        public string orderNumber { get; set; }
    }


 }
```